# Convert String To Date BRT

Tags: java, string, date, simpledateformat

I'm trying convert a String to Date, but I haven't gotten it.

My String is in the format:

```
"Fri Jun 13 10:24:01 BRT 2014"
```

I have Googled and found this resolution, but still continue catching an Exception.

Here is my code:

```
java.text.SimpleDateFormat df = new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss 'BRT' yyyy", Locale.getDefault());
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("BRT"));
try {
    return df.parse(dateString);
} catch (Exception e) {
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("BRT"));
DateFormat utcFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ");
Date d = df.parse("Fri Jun 13 10:24:01 BRT 2014");
System.out.println(utcFormat.format(d)); // output: 2014-06-13T12:24:01+0200
```

Consider following corrections:

1. `Locale.ENGLISH` instead of `Locale.getDefault()` enables reliable parsing of english names like "Jun" or "Fri"
2. **Use pattern symbol z** instead of literal 'BRT' because else the parser cannot interprete the string "BRT" as an abbreviation of a timezone name that is interpreting as Brazil Standard Time (in your case just parsing as literal hence not taking in account the timezone offset of UTC-03:00).

Answer (score 0):

The [answer by Meno Hochschild](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24262871/642706) is correct. Pay attention to those items (1) & (2).

## Joda-Time

FYI, using [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) or java.time (new package in [Java 8](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=3&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CD4QygQwAg&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8_.28March_18.2C_2014.29&ei=9kCgU56yNsf_oQTwpIC4Bw&usg=AFQjCNGA3cOm3jjwMNI0TZMA6V7aZJ_JdQ&sig2=pAbKxAkWb-CzomMHjxnBfw&bvm=bv.68911936,d.cGU)) is recommended over the notoriously troublesome java.util.Date and .Calendar classes.

Example in Joda-Time 2.3.

```
String input = "Fri Jun 13 10:24:01 BRT 2014";
```

Via a Locale object, specify the language by which to interpret the day-of-week and month names during the parsing.

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss z yyyy" ).withLocale( Locale.ENGLISH );
```

Rather than rely on the default, specify a time zone to assign to the fresh DateTime object resulting from the parsing. Unlike a java.util.Date object, a DateTime truly knows its own assigned time zone.

```
DateTimeZone timeZone = DateTimeZone.forID( "America/Sao_Paulo" ); // Arbitrary choice of example time zone.
DateTime dateTime = formatter.withZone( timeZone ).parseDateTime( input );
```

Usually you should be working in [Universal Time (UTC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC). Easy to convert.

```
DateTime dateTimeUtc = dateTime.withZone( DateTimeZone.UTC );
```

Built-in formatter is based on [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format.

```
String output = dateTime.toString();
```

Or define your own pattern, or use one of the other pre-defined formats.

```
String outputInAwkwardFormat = formatter.print( dateTime );
```